# SELECT FOR UPDATE query with Spring's @Transaction management creates deadlock upon subsequent updates

Tags: java, spring, oracle, transactions, weblogic

Setup: Spring application deployed on Weblogic 12c, using JNDI lookup to get a datasource to the Oracle Database.

We have multiple services which will be polling the database regularly for new jobs. In order to prevent two services picking the same job we are using a native `SELECT FOR UPDATE` query in a CrudRepository. The application then takes the resulting job and updates it to `PROCESSING` instead of `WAITING` using the `CrusRepository.save()` method.

The problem is that I can't seem to get the `save()` to work within the `FOR UPDATE` transaction (at least this is my current working theory of what goes wrong), and as a result the entire polling freezes until the default 10 minute timeout occurs. I have tried putting `@Transactional` (with various propagation flags) basically everywhere, but I'm not able to get it to work (`@EnableTransactionManagement` is activated and working).

Obviously there must be some basic knowledge I'm missing. Is this even a possible setup? Unfortunately, just using `@Transactional` with a non-native CrudRepository `SELECT` query is not possible, as it apparently first makes a `SELECT` to see if the row is locked or not, and only *then* makes a new `SELECT` that locks it. Another service could very well pick up the same job in the meanwhile, which is why we need it to lock immediately.

---

Update in relation to @M. Deinum's comment.: I should perhaps also mention that it's a setup wherein the central component that's doing the polling is a library used by all the other services (therefore the library has @SpringBootApplication, as does each service using it, so double component scanning is certainly present). Furthermore, the service has two separate classes for polling depending on the type of service, with a lot of common code, shared in an AbstractTransactionHelper class. Below I've aggregated some code for the sake of brevity.

The library's main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class JobsMain {

public static void initializeJobsMain(){
    PersistenceProviderResolverHolder.setPersistenceProviderResolver(new PersistenceProviderResolver() {

        @Override
        public List<PersistenceProvider> getPersistenceProviders() {
            return Collections.singletonList(new HibernatePersistenceProvider());
        }

        @Override
        public void clearCachedProviders() {
            //Not quite sure what this should do...
        }
    });
}

@Bean
public JtaTransactionManager transactionManager(){
    return new WebLogicJtaTransactionManager();
}

public DataSource dataSource(){
    final JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
    dsLookup.setResourceRef(true);
    DataSource dataSource = dsLookup.getDataSource("Jobs");
    return dataSource;
}

}
```

The repository (we're returning a set with only one job as we had some other issues when returning a single object):

```
public interface JobRepository extends CrudRepository<Job, Integer> {

@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM JOB WHERE JOB.ID IN "
                    + "(SELECT ID FROM "
                        + "(SELECT * FROM JOB WHERE "
                            + "JOB.STATUS = :status1 OR "
                            + "JOB.STATUS = :status2 "
                        + "ORDER BY JOB.PRIORITY ASC, JOB.CREATED ASC) "
                    + "WHERE ROWNUM <= 1) "
                + "FOR UPDATE", nativeQuery = true)
public Set<Job> getNextJob(@Param("status1") String status1, @Param("status2") String status2);
```

The transaction handling class:

```
@Service
public class JobManagerTransactionHelper extends AbstractTransactionHelper{

@Transactional
@Override
public QdbJob getNextJobToProcess(){
        Set<Job> jobs = null;
        try {
            jobs = jobRepo.getNextJob(Status.DONE.name(), Status.FAILED.name());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error(ex);
        }
    return extractSingleJobFromSet(jobs);
}
```

---

Update 2: Some more code.

AbstractTransactionHelper:

```
@Service
public abstract class AbstractTransactionHelper {

@Autowired
QdbJobRepository jobRepo;

@Autowired
ArchivedJobRepository archive;

protected Job extractSingleJobFromSet(Set<Job> jobs){
    Job job = null;
    if(jobs != null && !jobs.isEmpty()){
        for(job job : jobs){
            if(this instanceof JobManagerTransactionHelper){
                updateJob(job);
            }
            job = job;
        }
    }
    return job;
}

protected void updateJob(Job job){
    updateJob(job, Status.PROCESSING, null);
}

protected void updateJob(Job job, Status status, String serviceMessage){
    if(job != null){
        if(status != null){
            job.setStatus(status);
        }
        if(serviceMessage != null){
            job.setServiceMessage(serviceMessage);   
        }
        saveJob(job);
    }
}

protected void saveJob(Job job){
    jobRepo.save(job);
    archive.save(Job.convertJobToArchivedJob(job));
}
```

---

Update 4: Threading. newJob() is implemented by each service that uses the library.

```
@Service
public class JobManager{

@Autowired
private JobManagerTransactionHelper transactionHelper;

@Autowired
JobListener jobListener;

@Autowired
Config config;

protected final AtomicInteger atomicThreadCounter = new AtomicInteger(0);

protected boolean keepPolling;    
protected Future<?> futurePoller;
protected ScheduledExecutorService pollService;
protected ThreadPoolExecutor threadPool;

public boolean start(){
    if(!keepPolling){
        ThreadFactory pollServiceThreadFactory = new ThreadFactoryBuilder()
            .setNamePrefix(config.getService() + "ScheduledPollingPool-Thread").build();
        ThreadFactory threadPoolThreadFactory = new ThreadFactoryBuilder()
                            .setNamePrefix(config.getService() + "ThreadPool-Thread").build();
        keepPolling = true;
        pollService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(pollServiceThreadFactory);
        threadPool = (ThreadPoolExecutor)Executors.newFixedThreadPool(getConfig().getThreadPoolSize(), threadPoolThreadFactory);
        futurePoller = pollService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(getPollTask(), 0, getConfig().getPollingFrequency(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

protected Runnable getPollTask() {
    return new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                while(atomicThreadCounter.get() < threadPool.getMaximumPoolSize() && 
                        threadPool.getActiveCount() < threadPool.getMaximumPoolSize() && 
                        keepPolling == true){
                    Job job = transactionHelper.getNextJobToProcess();
                    if(job != null){
                        threadPool.submit(getJobHandler(job));
                        atomicThreadCounter.incrementAndGet();//threadPool.getActiveCount() isn't updated fast enough the first loop
                    }else{
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                logger.error(e);
            }
        }
    };
}

protected Runnable getJobHandler(final Job job){
    return new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                atomicThreadCounter.decrementAndGet();
                jobListener.newJob(job);
            }catch(Exception e){
                logger.error(e);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: The fact that it works with a timeout makes me wonder your transaction setup is even correct. You don't have duplicate component scans in your configuration by any change? Please add some code and configuration.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it wasn't. How would duplicate component scan (which is certainly present) affect the transaction handling?

Comment: How is the `getNextJobToProcess` invoked? Is it an internal method call?

Comment: It is invoked by a runnable that's executed once every X seconds (potentially by several threads running in parallell) in a ThreadPool. This is how the application polls the database regularly for new jobs.

Comment: Let me rephrase what is calling the method. I get the impression that it is called from a method somewhere in the `AbstractTransactionHelper` as an internal method call instead an external method call.

Comment: Nope, it's called from a separate class called JobManager. We've already been through the problem I suspect you're referring to, i.e. that internal method calls don't work with transactions. However, extractSingleJobFromSet, which in turn updates the status of the Job through some subsequent method calls, are all internal in JobManagerTransactionHelper. Not sure if this is affecting things? Adding the relevant code to the question.

Comment: You are also mentioning a runnable how is it getting a reference to that bean? IN other words how are you doing the threading.

Comment: What I also don't get is what is the `PersistenceProviderResolverHolder` doing, it makes me shudder a bit looks like you are doing strange things with your entity manager. Also `@EnableTransactionManagement` is already  provided by spring boot so shouldn't be necessary. The same for `@EnableJpaRepositories` only the `@SpringBootApplication` is needed. I also expected a `main` method be present but it isn't how is your application bootstrapped?

Comment: Also instead of doing `FOR UPDATE` add `@Lock(PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)` instead. As that will tell hibernate to use pessimistic locking. You also might want to add `isolation=SERIALIZABE` to your `@Transactional` if it is import to have single access.

Comment: The PersistenceProviderResolverHolder code was required in order to make the application deployable on Weblogic. Why I do not know, and I openly admit that a lot of the magic going on is beyond my understanding (which explains why we're having problems now). Since it's just a library there is no main method. The applications using it also don't have any main method since they are deployed on a managed application server, and polling is started using a GET to a RESTController.

Comment: The reason we are using `FOR UPDATE` instead of `@Lock` is that `@Lock` first makes a non-locking `SELECT` before making another `SELECT` that actually locks the row. Thus making the lock pointless since something else could come inbetween and lock the row. I'm updating the question since technically, it's not Transaction doing this (as I first wrote), but `@Lock`.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, the problem was the `WeblogicJtaTransactionManager`. My guess is that the `FOR UPDATE` resulted in a JPA transaction, but upon updating the object in the database, the `WeblogicJtaTransactionManager` was used, which failed to find an ongoing JTA transaction. Since we're deploying on Weblogic we wrongly assumed we had to use the `WeblogicJtaTransactionManager`.

Either way, exchanging the `TransactionManager` to a `JpaTransactionManager` (and explicitly setting the `EntityManagerFactory` and `DataSource` on it) basically solved all problems.

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
    jpaTransactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
    jpaTransactionManager.setJpaDialect(new HibernateJpaDialect());
    return jpaTransactionManager;
}
```

Assuming you also have added an EntityManagerFactoryBean which is needed if you want to use multiple datasources in the same project (which we're doing, but not within single transactions, so no need for JTA).

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

    factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("my.model");

    return factoryBean;
}
```